# Running a script from a mongodb docker-container

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have script that restores the database `restore.sh`:

```sh
mongorestore --port 27017 --db myapp `pwd`/db-dump/myapp
```

I want to run this in a short lived docker-container using the image [mvertes/alpine-mongo](https://hub.docker.com/r/mvertes/alpine-mongo/).

To run a shortlived container the `--rm`is used:

```sh
docker run --rm --name mongo -p 27017:27017 \
  -v /data/db:/data/db \
  mvertes/alpine-mongo
```

But how do I execute my script in the same command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/):

```
 $ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

You can pass in the command you wish to execute. In your case, this could be the restore script. You must consider two things, though.

- The script is not part of the container, so you need to mount into the container.
- Specifying a command overwrites the `CMD` directive in the Dockerfile.

If you look at the Dockerfile, you see this as its last line:

```
CMD [ "mongod" ]
```

This means the default command that the container executes is `mongod`. When you specify a command for `docker run`, you "replace" this with the command you pass in. In your case: Passing in the restore script will overwrite `mongod`, which means Mongo never starts and the script will fail.

You have two options:

1. Start one container with the database and another one with the restore script.
2. Try to chain the commands.

Since you want to run this in a short-lived container, option 2 might be better suited for you. Just remember to start `mongod` with the `--fork` flag to run it in daemon mode.

```
$ docker run --rm --name mongo -p 27017:27017 \
-v /data/db:/data/db \
-v "$(pwd)":/mnt/pwd \
mvertes/alpine-mongo "mongod --fork && /mnt/pwd/restore.sh"
```

Hopefully, this is all it takes to solve your problem.